# App Store updating application

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I was wondering if I can compare an AppStore update on an application to running an app on the simulator, changing some code, then run it again? Or is the hole application reinstalling when you update an application from the AppStore?

I was wondering, because in my application I am using Key/Value method to save strings and integers to userDefaults, but I'm not sure if the strings and integers will be the same after an AppStore update or if they would be reset.

Comment: not so bad question, i asume its a full program install but keeping documents.

Comment: Where are you saving the key/value pairs? In user defaults?

Comment: do you think you are the first who asked that question? I think it's answered 5 times if you look through the related section

Comment: the _user defaults_ and the `Document` folder won't be touched when the application is upgraded.

Comment: Also note that when you update an app, resource files that are in the old app version but not in the new one remain on the device.